# JavaScript dynamically detect all CSS values

Tags: javascript, css

This script dynamically detects all the possible style properties an element supports...

```
for (i in document.getElementById('body').style)
{
 document.getElementById('q').value = document.getElementById('q').value+', '+i;
}
```

My question is how do we *dynamically* detect all possible `value`s that a given `property` supports? By dynamic I *clearly* mean not creating an array with possible values (static) and iterating over the array using `CSS.supports`.

Comment: Not that I can help, but just for clarification, do you wish to also include supported browser-prefixed properties?

Comment: if you mean you know some property name beforehand, just want to check if it's supported, so you can just use the `in` operator like `if("propetyName" in styleObject){...}` whereas `styleObject` is the object referenced by `style` property (of a DOM element object).

Comment: CSS.supports (`CSS.supports('position','absolute')`) would tell you if a value is supported, but you'd have to throw some strings at it...

Comment: @NickDugger Yes, including prefixed values.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that's possible since some are endless. You are really looking to see what classes of values are acceptable.

When the property value is a number like `top` it accepts `length` which can be `in, cm, mm, pt, pc, px, ex, em, percentage, auto, or inherit`

In the case of `content` it accepts a different range of values `normal, none, string's, uri's, counter, attr(attrName), open-quote, close-quote, no-open-quote, no-close-quote, inherit` (and it's possible it's looking for a combination of those things)

(src:[w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html))

Each property described in the w3 document has a different set of types that it accepts.

I don't know how to get javascript to spit out that kind of schema/dtd but you could come up with an exhaustive list of potential values that represent the classes of values and then test each using something like CSS.supports(propertyName,value);